# How to tell distance travelled by rail?

Tags: trains, europe, germany, russia, poland

I'm planning a long railway journey, and I wonder what the distance (to be) travelled is for a a particular route.  Is there any website where I can find this out, for example, based on stations included with HAFAS and on HAFAS-recommended routes?  For example, a journey from Berlin (Germany) to Inta (Russia) takes about three days and passes through Germany, Poland, Belarus, and Russia.

Comment: As far as Russia is concerned, most train routes have public data for the distance traveled by rail. For instance, if your plan is to take a train from Moscow to Inta directly, you will need to travel [2014 kilometers](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=367c5b61) by rail.
Since neither Google nor Yandex seem to "know" how to get to Inta by rail, I'm not sure there's a more automated option to calculate the optimal route. That said, I doubt you could do much better than taking a direct train.

Answer (score 7):

It's unclear to me where the data is being sourced from or how accurate it is, but Rome2Rio appears to have distances for each invididual segment.  For your example, it shows Berlin-Moscow as 1152 miles, and Moscow-Inta as 1230 miles, with a couple miles of subway across Moscow and a bit of walking as well.

From https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Berlin/Inta, click on the "Night train, train" option, then expand each segment.

[image: Screenshot for Berlin-Moscow]

Answer (score 2):

For trains connecting to and from Russia, there is route information on tutu.travel.  For example, [Route 018Б Nice → Moskva](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=49b8ef) reveals that the distance travelled from Nice to Moscow is 2958 km (and passing through eight countries).